# Regular expression for urlpattern

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I need a regexp for a URL like:

```
/slug/#slug/slug/
```

I know it should be something like:

```
r'^(?P<slug1>[-\w]+)/#(?P<slug2>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug3>[-\w]+)/$'
```

But I am having problems with the character `#`

Comment: Have you tried escaping the #? \#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter after # character is not send to server, so cannot catch in server side script like django.

Answer (score 2):

The URL fragment (everything after the `#`) is not sent to the server in a request.